# In Views, use group type's image in a field when a group content type is fitered

Tags: views, organic-groups

I currently have a view that filters through a certain content type, which is a group content type. I am displaying fields such as title, body and last comment. I would also like to add an image field, which comes from the content type's group.

Is there a way to do this in Views?

I am using Drupal 7, and Views 3.

Comment: That should just be a question of adding an image field to the content type. then adding this into the view just as you already have for title, body and last comment...?

Comment: The problem is that that image that I want is in the group type and not in the group content type. 

Example:

[Parent Content type fields (the group type):
Title, 
image = group_image]

[Child content type fields (The group content type):
Title,
Body,
Last Comment]

In the view:

[fields:
Title,
Body,
Last Comment,
group_image]

[Filter:
Child content type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the view field view module: http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view

I firstly created a view that filters through all of the group type's images. In the contextual filter I used the group id.

In the other view I used the view above as the view field and used the group id as the arguement.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup a relationship between the "Group Type" and "Group Content" content types. If the parent > child relationship is determined using Taxonomy you can use the "Taxonomy: Parent Term".

Then you can add the field for the image which comes from the parent (make sure you change the relationship to the parent tax) and have it on the same row the as children.

Comment: Actually, you might be able to use the relationship provided by Organic Groups rather than Taxonomy. You will need to do it the opposite way round tho I believe.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, do you know which relationship to use for the organic groups?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with OG 7.2, but I solved it *without* **views-field-view**.
Instead I used OGs own way:

I first made the relationship **OG membership: OG membership from Node** 
to get the OG-Membership of the Group-Content I want to show and then...

...I need the Node of the Group of the OG-Membership and that means I need to make the relationship **OG membership: Group Node from OG membership** using the first relationship.

So now I have 2 *relationships* :

- OG membership: OG membership from Node
- (OG membership from node) OG membership: Group Node from OG membership

And now I was able to get access to the fields of the related group by using the relation **Group Node from OG membership**